# Running Multiple Rspec Test metadata

Tags: ruby, testing, command-line, rspec

I am trying to run multiple tests in Rspec using metadata tags. I usually run test like, RSpec -t case_id:1234, THis works fine however, I want to be able to run multiple case_ids. I tried methods like RSpec -t case_id:1234, case_id:4321 and -t case_id:1234 && -t case:id:4321 this just make two separate test run creating two separate environments. I want both tests to be able to run in the same environment.

Comment: Glancing at [the docs for the `--tag name:value` option](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-9/docs/command-line/tag-option#filter-examples-with-a-%60name:value%60-tag), it seems that `value` is an exact comparison. There aren't any documented examples of `value` being an array or a regex. So, I think what you want is not currently possible.

Comment: That is what I assumed too, you broke down the values correctly. I wonder if there is any way to implement an array of text case ids somehow. It might be better to leave this alone since it is not a necessary item.